# Handling hidden and shown fragments onbackpressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity which hosts three `Fragment`'s and I can switch between `Fragment`'s using `BottomNavigationView`.The mechanism that I use to switch between `Fragment`'s is using `show` and `hide` functions of `FragmentTransaction` instead of `replace` function of `FragmentTransaction`. I am doing so because I want some network operations to be done only once and also to inflate `Layout` only once.

The problem that I am facing using this mechanism is that when I start another `Activity` from any of the `Fragment` and then hit the back button the selectedItem of the `BottomNavigationView` and the `Fragment` shown are mismatching.

I was able to solve this problem though but I feel it has less efficiency. The procedure was that whenever I clicked a tab in `BottomNavigation` while switching `Fragment`'s I gave it some predecided number and saved in a static variable(`X`) and whenever I clicked back button in the `OnResume()` method of the hosting activity I made a switch-case block using `X` to know which `Fragment` was visible before starting the new Activity and then finally making three `FragmentTransaction`'s to show and hide required `Fragment`'s.

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();


        if(selectedId!=63){
           switch(selectedId){
               case 0:if(bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId()==R.id.navigation_home){handleHomeFragmentVisibility();}
                   break;
               case 1:if(bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId()==R.id.navigation_dashboard)
               {handleDashboardFragmentVisibility();}
                   break;
               case 2:if(bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId()==R.id.navigation_notifications)
               {handleNotificationFragmentVisibility();}
                   break;
           }

        }
```

I feel using three `FragmentTransaction`'s is costly and I was looking for some efficient way. Can you tell me one if you know ?

```
public void handleHomeFragmentVisibility(){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=  getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("home") != null) {
            //if the fragment exists, show it.
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("home")).commit();
        } else {
            //if the fragment does not exist, add it to fragment manager.


            Log.e(TAG,"homeFragmentAdded");
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new HomeFragment(), "home").commit();
        }
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("dashboard") != null) {
            //if the other fragment is visible, hide it.
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("dashboard")).commit();
        }
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("requests") != null) {
            //if the other fragment is visible, hide it.
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("requests")).commit();
        }

    }

    public void handleDashboardFragmentVisibility(){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=  getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("dashboard") != null) {
            //if the fragment exists, show it.
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("dashboard")).commit();
        } else {
            //if the fragment does not exist, add it to fragment manager.

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new DashboardFragment(), "dashboard").commit();
        }
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("home") != null) {
            //if the other fragment is visible, hide it.
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("home")).commit();
        }
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("requests") != null) {
            //if the other fragment is visible, hide it.
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("requests")).commit();
        }

    }
    public void handleNotificationFragmentVisibility(){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=  getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("requests") != null) {
            //if the fragment exists, show it.
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("requests")).commit();
        } else {
            //if the fragment does not exist, add it to fragment manager.

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new NotificationFragment(), "requests").commit();
        }
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("home") != null) {
            //if the other fragment is visible, hide it.
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("home")).commit();
        }
        if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("dashboard") != null) {
            //if the other fragment is visible, hide it.
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("dashboard")).commit();
        }
    }

 bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        selectedId=0;
                       handleHomeFragmentVisibility();
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    selectedId=1;
                     handleDashboardFragmentVisibility();

                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                   selectedId=2;
                      handleNotificationFragmentVisibility();
                        break;

                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. I understand that after starting a new activity you want to be able to go back to the old activity and resume state. For this, you need to save a variable in the bundle of your activity and recover it once you come back. It could be an index of a list of fragments, for example. There is no need to call more than one `FragmentTransaction` and in the `onResume()` code you don't call any transactions. It is not particularly efficient to use an if-switch-if cascade when one switch statement would suffice, but it isn't too expensive either.

Comment: @KalaBalik I am using three transactions because I need to show one fragment and hide the other two fragment otherwise two or three fragments would be shown overlapping each other which is not intended. Each function that I call in the `if` block inisde `switch` has three transactions each to show and hide the required fragments.

Comment: @KalaBalik I have added implementations of functions called in `switch` statement to make you understand better.

Comment: Using `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` will simplify this a lot.

Comment: @H.Brooks I am using the same functions there as well. I have added the code of `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

Comment: Are you experiencing slow performance?

Comment: @H.Brooks It is working at fine speed as of now. Is there another way you could think of ?

Comment: Well there is nothing wrong with the way that you are doing it. If I was you I would keep it as is, its a lot of code for a simple function I know.

Comment: @H.Brooks I will do the same. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first note on your code: Avoid boilerplate! Write only one method instead of three and use a signature of the type `handleFragmentVisibility(String show, String hide1, String hide2, int container)`. In case the fragment to be shown is `null`, instantiate it by testing for `show`, something like:

```
Fragment newFragment = (show == "home") ? new HomeFragment() : (show == "dashboard") ? new DashboardFragment() : new NotificationFragment();
```

However, none of your fragments should ever get `null` through hiding (please check for yourself), since you don't `remove` them from your activity or `replace` them with other fragments. Instead of using `show` and `hide` you could also use `attach` and `detach`, both sets of methods keep state. I don't see an efficiency problem and you do indeed need to call three `FragmentTransaction`s. It only can be done with less code:

```
public void handleFragmentVisibility(String show, String hide1, String hide2){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(show)).commit();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(hide1)).commit();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(hide2)).commit();
    }
```

Please note, that although this method keeps the state of the fragment while hiding or detaching them, other events like orientation change still make it necessary that you take care of saving state in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)`.